# Centered responsive text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/kw83kLmo/

It's justs a block of text that I need to center in the window.

The text needs a set width because I don't want it to be the full width of the container.

When the window gets smaller the text needs to stay in the center but get narrower.

In the example here it stays centered and responds until it get's to 600px then just stays that width.

I know I have set that width but I did that to center it

```
<div class="container-fluid ">

    <div class="hero">

        <div class="hero_heading text-center">
            <h1>This is a heading This is a heading This is a heading </h1>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Any reason to use absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code like this :

```
.hero_heading h1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kw83kLmo/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Update your `h1` style like below.

```
.hero_heading h1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kw83kLmo/4/)

Comment: You could leave of the position absolute as well in this case. I tested it but since my answer would be the above, I'll just comment it :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit on your code

```
.hero_heading h1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    //top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 600px;/*added*/
    max-width:80%;/*to leave spaces around your text on responsive*/
    margin:auto;/*changed*/
}
```

You no need to position your element for making it unless if you need

NOTE: Remove your `position:relative;` from `.hero`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/kw83kLmo/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1v1hky8c/1/)

I took the positioning off the `h1` and put it on the wrapping div.

**CSS**

```
.hero{
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x300);  
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.hero_heading {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
.hero_heading{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);        
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS flex can do the magic for you in a compatible way across most popular browsers including IE. Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/mdfeo4hf/)

```
.hero{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;

    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x300);  
    background-size: cover;
    height: 400px;
}

.hero_heading h1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: white;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```